# Alfresco batch loading service for nodes metadata

Tags: web-services, batch-processing, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

In our project we are using `Alfresco 4.2-c` for content store. We need web service for nodes metadata loading. The required properties that should included in the result are `createdOn` or `modifiedOn`. We have the ids of the nodes, which dates should be retrieved. Is there any way of getting this properties for multiple notes in one request, not one by one.

I already tried `POST /alfresco/service/api/bulkmetadata`, but none of the properties that I need is included in the result.

I also tried to create search request, but it returns only `nodeRef` ids.

I am aware that there are services to get this information one by one, but I don't want that, because I need the information for over 40K nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enumerate the properties:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/?
   cmisselector=query
   &maxItems=10
   &skipCount=0
   &succinct=true
   &q=
     select cmis:objectId, cmis:createdBy, cmis:description
     from cmis:document 
     where 
        cmis:objectId in (
          '8dac37fa-1cd4-4226-85a3-03e8fdb64e16',
          '395417a9-4bd1-4dd1-b33c-c4e555abccae'
        )
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I'll try it as soon as I can and let you know, if this works.